# Sending code snippets in my react chat application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chat, code-snippets

I'm developing some chat application using React 17+ and I want to add a feature for user to send a code snippet message and make this code look fancy in messages container.

Like this `const msg = 'Hello'`

I understand that it is accomplishable with just JS and CSS but maybe someone knows some npm package for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://github.com/react-syntax-highlighter/react-syntax-highlighter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having some kind of syntax that allows code formatting, e.g. if the text is surrounded by three backticks (```). Then, while sending the message, you can implement a formatter that checks the syntax, styles it by e.g. adding a class and styling it with CSS or using something like [Prism.js](https://prismjs.com), and finally send the *styled* message.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you Prism.js  https://prismjs.com/ with  https://www.npmjs.com/package/prism-react-renderer for React.

For me It works very well for code snippets in blog posts (Gatsby mdx) as well as chat messages (@chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react).

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!